# Using Upstart to manage Unicorn w/ rbenv + bundler binstubs w/ ruby-local-exec shebang

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn, upstart

Alright, this is melting my brain. It might have something to do with the fact that I don't understand Upstart as well as I should. Sorry in advance for the long question.

I'm trying to use Upstart to manage a Rails app's Unicorn master process. Here is my current `/etc/init/app.conf`:

```
description "app"

start on runlevel [2]
stop on runlevel [016]

console owner

# expect daemon

script
  APP_ROOT=/home/deploy/app
  PATH=/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims:/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:$PATH
  $APP_ROOT/bin/unicorn -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production # >> /tmp/upstart.log 2>&1
end script

# respawn
```

That works just fine - the Unicorns start up great. What's not great is that the PID detected is not of the Unicorn master, it's of an `sh` process. That in and of itself isn't so bad, either - if I wasn't using the automagical Unicorn zero-downtime deployment strategy. Because shortly after I send `-USR2` to my Unicorn master, a new master spawns up, and the old one dies...and so does the `sh` process. So Upstart thinks my job has died, and I can no longer restart it with `restart` or stop it with `stop` if I want.

I've played around with the config file, trying to add -D to the Unicorn line (like this: `$APP_ROOT/bin/unicorn -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D`) to daemonize Unicorn, and I added the `expect daemon` line, but that didn't work either. I've tried `expect fork` as well. Various combinations of all of those things can cause `start` and `stop` to hang, and then Upstart gets really confused about the state of the job. Then I have to restart the machine to fix it.

I think Upstart is having problems detecting when/if Unicorn is forking because I'm using rbenv + the `ruby-local-exec` shebang in my `$APP_ROOT/bin/unicorn` script. Here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby-local-exec
#
# This file was generated by Bundler.
#
# The application 'unicorn' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'pathname'
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile",
  Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

load Gem.bin_path('unicorn', 'unicorn')
```

Additionally, the `ruby-local-exec` script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# `ruby-local-exec` is a drop-in replacement for the standard Ruby
# shebang line:
#
#    #!/usr/bin/env ruby-local-exec
#
# Use it for scripts inside a project with an `.rbenv-version`
# file. When you run the scripts, they'll use the project-specified
# Ruby version, regardless of what directory they're run from. Useful
# for e.g. running project tasks in cron scripts without needing to
# `cd` into the project first.

set -e
export RBENV_DIR="${1%/*}"
exec ruby "$@"
```

So there's an `exec` in there that I'm worried about. It fires up a Ruby process, which fires up Unicorn, which may or may not daemonize itself, which all happens from an `sh` process in the first place...which makes me seriously doubt the ability of Upstart to track all of this nonsense.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? From what I understand, the `expect` stanza in Upstart can only be told (via `daemon` or `fork`) to expect a maximum of two forks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

your upstart job needs to be configured so that upstart knows exactly how many times it forks.  And it can only fork once or twice, no more.

In unix land there are two key system calls that facilitate running programs: [`fork`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [`exec`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html).

`fork` copies the process that calls it.  One process calls `fork`, and it returns control back to two processes.  Each process must identify which it is (the parent or the child) from the value returned by fork (see the man page for details).

`exec` runs a new program, replacing the process that called `exec`.

When you simply run a command in a shell, the under the hood the shell calls `fork` to create a new process with its own id, and that new process (after some setup) immediately calls `exec` to start the command you typed.  This is how most programs are run, whether by shell or your window manager or whatever.
  See the [system](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/system.3.html) function in C, which also has variants in most of the scripting languages.

If you think it's inefficient, you're probably right.  It's how it has been done in unix since days of yore, and apparnetly nobody is game to change it.  One of the reasons is that there are many things that are *not* replaced on `exec`, including (sometimes) open files, and the process's user and group ids.

Another reason is that a LOT of effort has been spent making `fork` efficient, and they have actually done a pretty good job of it - in modern unixes (with the help of the CPU) `fork` actually copies very little of the process.  I guess nobody wants to throw all that work away.

And, (pause for effect) the processes pid.

To demonstrate:

```
mslade@mickpc:~$ echo $$
3652
mslade@mickpc:~$ bash
mslade@mickpc:~$ echo $$
6545
mslade@mickpc:~$ exec bash
mslade@mickpc:~$ echo $$
6545
mslade@mickpc:~$ exit
exit
mslade@mickpc:~$ echo $$
3652
```

Most of the popular languages have variations of fork and exec, including shell, C, perl, ruby and python.  But not java.

So with all that in mind, what you need to do to make your upstart job work is make sure that it forks the same number of times as upstart thinks it does.

The `exec` line in ruby-local-exec is actually a good thing, it prevents a fork.  Also `load` doesn't start a new process, it just loads the code into the existing ruby interpreter and runs it.

However your shell script forks in this line:

```
$APP_ROOT/bin/unicorn -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production # >> /tmp/upstart.log 2>&1
```

to prevent this you can just change it to

```
exec $APP_ROOT/bin/unicorn -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production # >> /tmp/upstart.log 2>&1
```

If you do that, AFAICT unicorn should not fork at all, and you won't need to tell upstart to expect a fork.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer! It just helped me to setup God+Upstart in the identical situation.